# Swift Package Manager compatible with which iOS versions?

Tags: xcode11, swift-package-manager

Is it possible to use Swift Package Manager on Xcode projects that support iOS 11 and above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

> The Swift Package Manager is included in Xcode 8.0 and all subsequent
>   releases.

Xcode 8, iOS SDK version is 10.0